# JavaScript $http.get an json array and store it in localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage, ionic-framework

I'm trying to receive an json Array and store it in the local storage. 
I've seen some questions like this but they couldn't help me. So i wanted to try with my own question. Im developing in Ionic Framework.

My controller includes following:

```
app.controller('QuestionsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $localstorage) {

$scope.getData = function() {

// get the json
   $http.get("data/fragenArray.json")
        .success(function(data) {

        //output of json as a string  -> correct
        console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

        // store json in local storage
        $localstorage.setObject('fragenset', data);

        // restore json from local storage
        var post = $localstorage.getObject('fragenset');

        // output of local storage item -> incorrect
        // I got: Test xxx: [object Object]
        console.log('Test xxx: ' + post);
     })
     .error(function(data) {
            alert("ERROR");
        });
    }
 });
```

To store the json I've got:

```
angular.module('utils', [])

 .factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
   return {
     set: function(key, value) {
       $window.localStorage[key] = value;
     },
     get: function(key, defaultValue) {
       return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
     },
     setObject: function(key, value) {
       $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
     },
     getObject: function(key) {
       return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
     }
   }
 }]);
```

So I decided to try it without the http.get request:

```
app.run(function($localstorage, $http) {
   $localstorage.setObject('post', {"fragen":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "frage":"Wie ist das Wetter?",
        "antworten": {
            "a_1":"gut",
            "a_2":"schlecht"
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "frage":"Wie geht es dir?",
        "antworten": {
            "a_1":"gut",
            "a_2":"schlecht"
        }
    }
 ]});
   var post = $localstorage.getObject('post');
   console.log(post);
 })
```

And the result ist exactly what i expected - an json object.

So how can i store the json array from the http.get correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know your data retrieval is working correctly because it passes the test written with `JSON.stringify()`:

```
// get the json
   $http.get("data/fragenArray.json")
        .success(function(data) {

        //output of json as a string  -> correct
        console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

        // store json in local storage
        $localstorage.setObject('fragenset', data);

        // restore json from local storage
        var post = $localstorage.getObject('fragenset');

        // output of local storage item -> incorrect
        // I got: Test xxx: [object Object]
        console.log('Test xxx: ' + post);
     })
```

The last test is a bad test.  It is not the result that is incorrect.  The coding of the test is incorrect.

This is because you can not inspect an object by appending it to a string.

If X is an object, then no matter what X contains, 
perhaps `X = {'a': 123}`

```
console.log("anything "+X); 
// --> "anything [object Object]"
```

This is because `"anything "+X` is a *string expression* and when an object is coerced to string, Javascript replaces the object with the string "[object Object]"

Here is what you should test instead:

```
 //output of storage as a json string  
 console.log('post: ' + JSON.stringify(post));
```

and finally

```
 // json string of storage matches json string of input data
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data)===JSON.stringify(post));
 // will yield true or false
```

Comment: Ok, well that works fine. Thank you. BUT then i get the result as a string. If i would like to do something like: 
$scope.questions= post.frage[i].id 
It doesn't work because it isn't an object. My aim ist to make one get request. Store it local and later i will fill in some views, labels etc.

Sorry but i'm really new to JS. ;-)

Comment: In the code above, post is an object.  Why do you think it is a string?  Because a string was printed out?